# integration of Angularjs in nvd3

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, d3.js, nvd3.js

currently i am using only nv.d3.js for my chart plotting. but they are not that much customizable that i need. i want to create fully customized nvd3 chart. am looking for solution so i can fully customized my chart, like in multibarchart i want to display bars values and many other stuffs.

This first option that i came to understand is Angularjs. what if i want to integrate the angular in my nv.d3 project . is it complicated or not possible please suggest me something.

Note : i have purely nv.d3 and d3 chart no other lib using

Vikas Kumar

Answer (score 0):

Why reinvent the wheel? There is already an angular directive for nvd3: [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/)

Comment: Tarun I have already Code so much. i dont want to code again for same things .. thats why am asking for integration with nvd3 of angular